# Calling some line of parent methods and then call child method.. possible? ways?

Tags: oop, inheritance, code-reuse

See the code below

```
Class A    
{
    method1 ()
    {
        code;
        code;//I want to run the code at this point and then resume with the child class method 
        code;//dont want this code If called from derived class
    }
}
Class B:A
{
    method1()
    {
        super();// Calling method1 of class A
    }
}
```

Please suggest how many ways I can achieve this. I don't want to re write the same code that is in method1 of class A.

Comment: Why? And you  mean "super.method1();" right?

Comment: I don't think that can be done.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch otherwise I would have to re write the class A code in Class B

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```
Class A{
    method1 (){
        code;
        method2(); // common code
        code;//dont want this code If called from derived class
    }
    method2(){
        code;//I want to run the code at this point and then resume with the child class method 
    }
}

Class B:A{
    method1(){
        super.method2();// Calling method2 of class A
    }
}
```

In general, if you want to reuse/override a fragment of a method, consider dividing it into subroutines, which can be independently called/overriden from a subclass. This is somehow similar to the [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern.